# Why is Selenium form-submit returning with all fields missing?

Tags: php, drupal, selenium

**MOST RECENT EDIT :: SOLUTION TO PROBLEM FOUND**

It turns out I was using the wrong element id for submit button, because I thought there was only 1 form on the page .. but there was a 2nd one way down at the bottom I hadn't seen.  So I think my question is on one hand maybe not relevant or correct.

However, the answer from @Purus below I think is valuable because it points out that in Se, forms should be submitted with ->submit() and element with ->click() .

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am writing an Se (Selenium) test harness for a Drupal-based web site.  I am encountering this issue that I do not understand.  It goes like this:

1. I have a script that will login and navigate to a Create User page
2. When the script fills in the fields - ***partially*** Or ***completely*** - the form is always returning with all fields missing .. as if nothing was entered.  Yet watching the browser, I can see the fields are populated.
3. When I drive the browser and navigate manually through the same steps, and even do just a partial filling out of the form - those fields I did fill in, are shown again when the page reloads telling me I didn't complete the form.

So if I entered 'abc' for the first field when driving the browser myself, the string 'abc' appears in the same field when the form reloads.

When Se is driving the steps, this **does not** happen - all entered fields are missing when the form is submitted and reloads.

**BROWSER CONSIDERATION**

In searching for a solution, some folks said it could be a browser issue.  Using the Facebook web driver, I have reproduced the same problem/issue in Firefox and Chrome.

**DRUPAL CONSIDERATION**

Is it possible it could be related to Drupal .. ? .. but I don't see how, since from Drupal's perspective - manual browsing or Se browsing, looks the same as I understand it.

However, the things that does make me think it could be something with how Drupal is setting up the form, is that I am able to access the login form successfully on the same site with Se.  So it works for one form, but not the other .. ?!

**EXAMPLE**

Below is the body of the entire test script.  The env. setup is PHPUnit with the Facebook PHP WebDriver for Se, running on OS X Mavericks

```
require_once './path_config.php';
class FormDemoTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static $LOGIN_PAGE_URL = 'https://dev.abc.com/login/';
    public static $FORM_PAGE_URL = 'https://dev.abc.com/create-user';

    var $driver;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
        $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->driver->quit();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testCreateForm()
    {
        $id = 'jules';
        $pwd = '22';
        $this->driver->get(self::$LOGIN_PAGE_URL);
        $this->findElementById('login')->sendKeys($id);
        $this->findElementById('pwd')->sendKeys($pwd);
        $this->findElementById('submit')->click();

        sleep(1);

        $this->driver->get(self::$FORM_PAGE_URL);
        $this->findElementById('first')->sendKeys('abc');
        $this->findElementById('last')->sendKeys('efg');
        $this->findElementById('submit')->click();

        $expectedTitle = "Create User";
        self::assertEquals($expectedTitle, $this->driver->getTitle());
    }

    public function findElementById($id=null) {
        return $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id($id));
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click and submit are different for a form.

Can you try submit() instead of click() ?

Instead of this:

```
$this->findElementById('submit')->click();
```

Try this:

```
$this->findElementById('login')->submit();
```

submit() method submits the form and you can call that from any element and its corresponding values are submitted.

Comment: You make a great point here - that there is the submit() method, and that's what should be used for forms; thank you for this insight.   Unfortunately, I am still seeing the same issue - where submitting the form reloads the page with the fields that I had entered as empty.  The only change I made to the code is as you suggested, to change calls to ->click(), to now be ->submit().  Strange situation seems to me .. ?!

Comment: Any url for me to check?

Comment: Hi @Purus, I am waiting on approval from the project mgr. to share a url. I appreciate your attention to this thread. Regards

Comment: Sure. That would be fine.